# How to use ArrayList with Hashmap

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to take String data in ArrayList. I attempted to retrieve forecast data (which is in JSON format) from OpenWeatherMap API.
  "I stored data in JSONObject,then take it in string. Now I want to show data with help of ArrayList,But I am not able to retrive data in ArayList. I had debug code with LogCat and found that all the String have data but ArrayList is not taking data." 
 Can anyone tell me where i am doing wrong.Below is my code of OnpostExecute method. Thanks for any help.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

    String gradfix = city.replace("%20", " ");
    grad.setText(gradfix);
    pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    grad.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    try {
        // Getting Array of Contacts
        JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(file_url);
        JSONArray forecast = null;
        forecast = json2.getJSONArray("list");

        // looping through All Contacts
        for(int i = 0; i < forecast.length(); i++){

            JSONObject c = forecast.getJSONObject(i);
            String dt = c.getString("dt");          
            String day = c.getString("day");
            Log.e("day",day.toString());
            String min = c.getString("min");
            String max = c.getString("max");
            String pressure = c.getString("pressure");
            String humidity = c.getString("humidity");

            JSONArray weather = c.getJSONArray("weather");

            for(int index = 0; index < weather.length(); index++){
                JSONObject weatherObject = weather.getJSONObject(index);
                String clouds = weatherObject.getString("clouds");
                String speed = weatherObject.getString("speed");
                String deg = weatherObject.getString("deg");
            }

        }

        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
        for (HashMap<String, Object> map : list) {

            //HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            //Log.e("list",pressure.toString());
            double srednja = Double.parseDouble(map.get("day").toString());
            double ssrednja2 = (double) Math.floor(srednja);
            srednja1.setText(format.format(ssrednja2)+"°F");
            tlak.setText(map.get("pressure").toString()+" hpa");
            tlak.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            vlaznost.setText(map.get("humidity").toString()+" %");
            vlaznost.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            vjetar.setText(map.get("speed").toString()+" m/s");
            vjetar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            String imgrestring = map.get("icon").toString();
            Bitmap slika = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), getResources().getIdentifier("img"+imgrestring, "drawable", getPackageName()));
            img_mid.setImageBitmap(slika);
            Float stupnjevi = Float.valueOf(map.get("deg").toString());
            Log.d("jea", String.valueOf(stupnjevi));
            Bitmap bmpOriginal = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.wind);
            Bitmap bmResult = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpOriginal.getWidth(), bmpOriginal.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(bmResult); 
            tempCanvas.rotate(stupnjevi, bmpOriginal.getWidth()/2, bmpOriginal.getHeight()/2);
            tempCanvas.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0, 0, null);
            BitmapDrawable mDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bmResult);
            vjetar.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( null, null, mDrawable, null);
            stanje.setText(map.get("main").toString());
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (HashMap<String, Object> map : list) {` you are iterating on a list that you just created. it is empty. what else did you expect?

Comment: The best option would be to deserialize the JSON data into some custom Java class. Or, in your current approach, you could do what you need inside the weather.length() loop - because here you iterate through the actual weather information object.

Comment: Your `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> list` is empty, only initialized, therefore you will never enter in for loop.

Comment: @njzk2 Yeah value of list is null. I want to know, how to insert values in list from string variable (dt,day,min,max etc). I am missing some syntax there.

Comment: You need to put things in your list. You are iterating on your JSON objects, but you are not doing anything with what you are reading. Put those values in maps and in your list.

Comment: What do you want to put in that map? Maybe `weatherObject` from previous for loop? `map.put(someString, someObject); list.add(map)`

Comment: @njzk2 I have remain code with change city name, Please can you tell me the syntax that how to put value in list.

Comment: @Drez I have changed all the value in string.If I use map.put(), It will show  error with String.

Comment: First, you have to understand your requirements. Why did you decide to have an array list of hash maps? Then, what do you want to store in the map? Since hash map stores key/value pairs, you decided to have a String as a key and Object as a value. What would be your key, which unique String? If you want to store that `weatherObject` you have to convert it from JSONObject to "regular" Object. Make a class Weather which will contain appropriate setters and getters (setCloud, getCloud etc). Than put that Object in the map, and change definition of the map to e.g. `HashMap<String, Weather>`.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is too long for comment, I will put this example in answer:

Example:

```
JSONObject weatherObject;
String clouds;
String speed;
String deg;
String id;

MyWeatherObject myWeatherObject;

final ArrayList<HashMap<String, MyWeatherObject>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, MyWeatherObject>>();
HashMap<String, MyWeatherObject> map;

for (int index = 0; index < weather.length(); index++) {
    weatherObject = weather.getJSONObject(index);
    clouds = weatherObject.getString("clouds");
    speed = weatherObject.getString("speed");
    deg = weatherObject.getString("deg");
    myWeatherObject = new MyWeatherObject();

    myWeatherObject.setClouds(clouds);
    myWeatherObject.setSpeed(speed);
    myWeatherObject.setDeg(deg);

    // some unique String/Integer/... which is kind of ID for weatherObject
    id = weatherObject.getString("id");

    map = new HashMap<String, MyWeatherObject>();

    map.put(id, myWeatherObject);

    // then, if you really want to put it in the array list, do it here
    list.add(map);
    // you can always store your data only in map, but then your map should not be initialized inside for loop
    // most likely you don't need an array list of the maps, but that I cannot see that from your example. 
    // Seems like you need only a hash map or an array list of pairs or an array list of MyWeatherObjects.

}

// your list is not empty anymore if your JSONArray/JSONObject is not empty
for (HashMap<String, MyWeatherObject> map : list) {
    // here you can reach your MyWeatherObject and there you have getClouds, getSpeed, getDeg...
}
```